# Understanding a simple http request

Tags: http, post, http-headers

In some tutorial , i have this request structure :

```
POST /apps/thinghttp/send_request HTTP/1.1
Host: api.thingspeak.com
Connection: close
Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded
Content-Length: (number of characters in message)

api_key=(thinghttp_api_key)&number={phone_number_to_call}
```

I am trying to understand a few things about it :

1. where they say "(api_key)" and "{phone number..}" do they have to be inside the brackets or do you takes out the brackets ?
2. What is the content length ? (they just dont say that )
3. I would like to test it using https://www.hurl.it  , and i cant understand where goes the last line ? i know the first line is in the post field, and the others are headers . but what about the last line- where it goes in this website ?

thanks .

http://community.thingspeak.com/tutorials/twilio/make-calls-with-twilio-using-the-thinghttp-app/

Answer (score 1):

1. No you don't have to use brackets, they are posted along with what's inside of the brackets, the { } are just used to let you know that what's inside of them has to be edited by yourself.
2. The length in bytes of the message body. The message body in a POST request are all post parameters and values : `api_key=(thinghttp_api_key)&number={phone_number_to_call}` in this case.
3. Those are the post parameters you send along with the http request. `api_key` is the name of one of the post parameter and `(thinghttp_api_key)` is it's value. The ampersand `&` is used to add another POST parameter which is `number` in this case followed by the value `{phone_number_to_call}`.

Comment: Thanks very much its a good answer. but regarding number 3 , i dont get, where is it goes in the website i have showed here ? the body ?  and also regarding number 2 ,you said, the length is the length of the post-so its the first raw and you showed the last row... i have a little bit mess here.

Comment: also if the first raw and the last row are both post parameters , why are they separated always ? why the last row is not coming right after the first row(the POST request row)

Comment: No, all of the rows are HTTP headers, POST meaning the method of sending the message body, then the path of where to and then the HTTP version which is 1.1. The actual body of the HTTP request starts after the first whiteline.